# How to add 10000 to existing column?

Tags: sql, nexusdb

I have a table called stock and one of the column is called stock_code. The stock_code is all 5 digit int (I believe), but now I'm running out of numbers, I need to change all the code to 10 digit. So I need to add 10000 to all the stock_code. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Please add sample input and output, also the query you hv tried so far.

Comment: What is the type of the `stock_code` column, and which database are you using?

Comment: For example: Apple Product code 20706 will become Apple Product Code 1000020706

Comment: you are still not mentioned the datatype of `stock_code` and the `RDBMS` you are using..

Comment: Database is NexusDB v2, I think it's SQL:2003

Comment: That's not *adding* 10000 to STOCK_CODE, but *concatenating* 10000 with STOCK_CODE. That would be an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's not adding, should be concatenating

Comment: Why not simply continue with 6 digit numbers? If your current highest stock_code is 99999 then just continue with 100000. I don't see any reason why you would need to change _existing_ values for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a number:

```
UPDATE stock SET stock_code = 1000000000 + stock_code;
```

or, to keep a better view on the number of zeros:

```
UPDATE stock SET stock_code = (10000 * 10000) + stock_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle:

```
update your_table set stock_code=concat(10000,stock_code)
```

For NexusDB

```
 update your_table SET stock_code = '10000' + stock_code
```

Comment: I tried this before, but got this error message: NexusDB: Query: Query execution failed; Unexpected exception object raised: [exception] unknow function:concat at line 1, pos 31

Comment: use concat operator using + operator we can use it in nexusdb i will edit my answer with that wait ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, (hope your `stock_code` column is string)

```
UPDATE stock SET stock_code = '10000' + stock_code
```

this will concatenate `10000` to your existing column `stock_code`.

If the stock_code column is `numeric`, then you can simply use the below query

```
UPDATE stock SET stock_code = 1000000000 + stock_code
```